# SQL: Can I force query to group by calculated week-ending date when the date format is DATETIME?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime

I'm using SQL 2008 R2.

I'm trying to write a query to aggregate total numbers of examinations, and present the totals by week-ending date, in a table, like this:

```
Week Ending | CT  | MRI | Ultrasound
------------+-----+-----+-----------
 10-09-2017 | 109 | 234 |   342
 03-09-2017 | 123 | 654 |   234
```

I've been using the following function to calculate week-ending dates from a date variable:

`SELECT 
     DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, exam_date)), exam_date) [Week Ending date]`

Using this function and then grouping by this function when the date variable format is simply DATE, has been working fine for me in previous queries against other tables.

However, problem I'm finding querying against the current table is that because the 'exam_date' variable is in DATETIME format, when I try to group by the same statement, it's grouping on both date and time (and therefore in effect, listing every single record as a separate row unless the DATETIME variable matches to the millisecond).

I've tried several permutations of CASTING and CONVERTING the exam_date variable into 105 format, but the code simply errors. I'm assuming I'm getting my syntax wrong. Efforts include:

```
DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, (CONVERT(DATE, exam_date))exam_date), exam_date) 
DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, CONVERT (varchar(10),exam_date,105))), exam_date)
```

Errors:

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Please can anyone advise if it's possible to force the query to group by the DATE part of the DATETIME variable, and if so, where am I going wrong in my code please?

For reference, full (base) query I'm using is:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;

SELECT 
     DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, exam_date)), exam_date) [Week Ending date]
    ,SUM(case when modality_name = 'C - CT' then 1 else 0 end) [CT]
    ,SUM(case when modality_name = 'M - MRI' then 1 else 0 end) [MRI]
    ,SUM(case when modality_name = 'U - Ultrasound' then 1 else 0 end) [Ultrasound]


FROM dbo.Diagnostics

WHERE 
        exam_date > '2016-08-27'
    AND GETDATE() > DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, exam_date)), exam_date)  

GROUP BY 
     DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, exam_date)), exam_date)

ORDER BY 
     DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, exam_date)), exam_date) desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to date to get rid of the time:

```
CONVERT( DATE, DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, exam_date)), exam_date) ) AS [Week Ending date]

GROUP BY CONVERT( DATE, DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, exam_date)), exam_date) )

ORDER BY CONVERT( DATE, DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, exam_date)), exam_date) )
```

Comment: Works perfect @Thorsten_Kettner thanks for your help.